# I want to share audio files in my list view to whatsapp . I assigned a share button on list items. The code has some problem

Tags: android

This is the code for the share button.  The thing is, sharing is not working when pressed the send button

```
viewHolder.ivSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            StringBuilder dataString = new StringBuilder();

            int song = music.getSong();

            dataString.append("Song :"+ song + "\n");

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(dataString.toString());
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("audio/mp3");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));

        }
    });
```

Comment: check with debugger if you are getting correct URI, etc.

Comment: (I just noticed that you are getting something like `Song :29` in your Uri, which is not a valid URI)